# Python: Maximum recursion depth while getting the str of an object

Tags: python, recursion

I'm making a program to get the amount of letters in a number:

```
def convert(number):
    lettercount = 0

    numstr = str(number)

    # One's places
    if len(numstr) is 1:
        if number == 1 or number == 2 or number == 6:
            lettercount += 3

        elif number == 4 or number == 5 or number == 9:
            lettercount += 4

        else:
            lettercount += 5

    # Ten's places
    elif len(numstr) is 2:
        if number == 10:
            lettercount += 3

        elif number == 11 or number == 12:
            lettercount += 6

        elif number == 15 or number == 16:
            lettercount += 7

        elif number == 13 or number == 14 or number == 19:
            lettercount += 8

        elif number == 17 or number == 18:
            lettercount += 9

        elif number == 20 or number == 30 or number == 40 or\
            number == 80 or number == 90:
            lettercount += 6

        else:
            lettercount += convert(int((numstr)[-1]))
            lettercount += convert(int(round(number, -1)))

    return lettercount

print "88 has %i letters in its name." % convert(88)
print "23 has %i letters in its name." % convert(23)
print "46 has %i letters in its name." % convert(46)
```

It works just fine and returns a correct response for the 88 and 23, but it gives a recursion depth error on 46. I'm confused; why does it happen on just 46?

---

Fixed code:

```
def convert(number):
    lettercount = 0

    numstr = str(number)

    # One's places
    if len(numstr) == 1:
        if number == 1 or number == 2 or number == 6:
            lettercount += 3

        elif number == 4 or number == 5 or number == 9:
            lettercount += 4

        else:
            lettercount += 5

    # Ten's places
    elif len(numstr) == 2:
        if number == 10:
            lettercount += 3

        elif number == 40 or number == 50:
            lettercount += 5

        elif number == 11 or number == 12 or number == 20 or number == 30 or\
            number == 80 or number == 90:
            lettercount += 6

        elif number == 15 or number == 16:
            lettercount += 7

        elif number == 13 or number == 14 or number == 19:
            lettercount += 8

        elif number == 17 or number == 18:
            lettercount += 9

        else:
            lettercount += convert(int((numstr)[-1]))
            lettercount += convert((int(numstr) // 10) * 10)

    return lettercount

print "88 has %i letters in its name." % convert(88)
print "23 has %i letters in its name." % convert(23)
print "46 has %i letters in its name." % convert(46)
```

Comment: because `round(46, -1)` is `50`.

Comment: Tip: don't use `len(numstr) is 2`, use `len(numstr) == 2` because `is` only returns `True` if both objects are on the same memory spot; `==` returns `True` if the value is the same.

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND For a simple integer like 2, the `is` test will always work, since it is an immutable type, so all instances of it are at the same memory.  But I agree that in general `is` should only be used when one wants to check that two objects are actually the same object.

Comment: Thanks you guys. I also spotted an error in my code; I need to round down, always. Time to figure that out! haha

Comment: @lxop: Actually, the `is` test only works due to the small `int` cache in the CPython reference interpreter (it's an implementation detail). There is no guarantee that `2` is a singleton in any other Python interpreter, nor in future versions of CPython, and it's definitely not a matter of *all* `int`s being singletons (the small `int` cache covers numbers from `-5` to `256` IIRC, so each reference to `257` creates a new `257`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you do

```
convert(int(round(number, -1)))
```

you are calling `convert(50)`.  Since 50 isn't covered by your `if` statements, it gets to the `else` again, and calls `convert(50)` again, and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `round(46, -1)` will produce the value `50`.  When `convert` is called with the value `50` it will go to the exact same line

```
lettercount += convert(int(round(number, -1)))
```

The `round(50, -1)` call will produce `50` and at this point the `convert` function will execute infinitely